# error on front end of website

Tags: magento2, error

I am getting this error when trying to load the homepage of the website:

> a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:13313:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/fakedomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()

any idea whats wrong or how to get around this?

Comment: Try to do a bin/magento... cache:flush, setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile

Comment: Looks like var/generation is not writable. Make sure to set proper file system ownership and permissions. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: I tried those suggestions and am still getting the same error.